# How to Modify SharePoint 2013 My Site Promoted Links

Tags: sharepoint-2013

I'm trying to do something that should be really easy, I think.  I just want to add additional tiles to the promoted links section so that when users click on the "Sites" header link they will see a list of the main company sites. How do I do I use this feature?

Comment: Office365 or On-premises?  Do you have admin rights for the MySite site collection?

Comment: on-premises and I am a farm admin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Central Admin go to the User Profile Application settings.  Under My Site Settings you'll see a link to "Manage Promoted Sites".  After that it is straightforward on how to add a promoted site.

This [link](http://www.brainlitter.com/2012/12/22/sharepoint-2013-promoted-sites-just-what-are-they/) has detailed steps.